# to stay the recent convictions

Tags: phrase-meaning

A B.C. Supreme Court judge rejected an application Wednesday **to stay** the recent convictions in the high-profile Surrey Six mass murder case. ('Surrey Six mass murder convictions upheld' CBC Nov. 19 2014)

Is '**to stay**' modifies 'an application' meaning '**to postpone**'?

Comment: The _application to stay_ was rejected.  You are imagining that by rejecting the application, the judge stayed the convictions?  That would be something more like: _A B.C. Supreme Court judge rejected an application Wednesday, **staying** the recent convictions in the high-profile Surrey Six mass murder case._

Comment: http://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/stay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost. "to stay" combines with **"the recent convictions"**, meaning "to postpone". The entire phrase "to stay the recent convictions …" is what modifies "an application". The application was a request that the convictions be postponed.

Step by step:

> [ the recent convictions … ]

Identifies and describes the convictions.

> [ to stay [ the recent convictions … ] ]

Means "to postpone the convictions".

> [ an application [ to stay [ the recent convictions … ] ] ]

Means "an application requesting that the convictions be postponed".